# In My Hero Academia season 6 episode 5, who dies because of the incident caused by Shigaraki?

Tags: my-hero-academia

In My Hero Academia season 6 episode 5 of the anime, Shigaraki ...

> wakes up and destroys the hospital he was in and the surroundings, a large portion of a city, and there were a lot of heroes around. Which heroes died when Shigaraki destroyed the hospital and its surroundings?

Comment: Spoilers tags/warning would’ve been nice, since this is the most recent episode :(

Comment: @Wondercricket it's impossible to make the question without spoilers in the title (where you can't use spoilers tags, and which has the same spoiler than in the body) and this probably happened over a year ago in the manga. Technically in a Questions and Answers anime board, 99% of the content is spoilers, the only sure way not to be spoiled here about a particular topic is to add a franchise to the ignore tag.

Comment: It is hard to tell because the events are ongoing as it is the latest episode. It will be revealed in upcoming episodes.